# Get specific number of points on Google Area Chart?

Tags: c#, sql, google-visualization

I don't know how to correctly explain the situation in the question. The scenario is that I have to show the data in the google Area chart. The data can be consist of 100 records or it can be of 1000 records. X-Axis is the Time for the record and Y-Axis is the value. I want to show 100 records on the chart if the record count is greater then or equal to 100. Means if the records count are 200 then still the 100 points will be plotted on the chart by group by the data or some other logic. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code to plot 100 fixed points in Y-Axis

```
 var options = {
                 vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 100} }
            };
```